# zslider javascript should work only in screen resolution below 768px

Tags: javascript

i want to use zslider javascript in my website, but can any one tell me how to make it work only in screen resolution below 768px

Here is the zslider script link:

```
http://www.cssscript.com/demo/mobile-friendly-content-carousel-slider-with-pure-javascript-zslider/
```

Answer (score 0):

Use media queries to show slider content below 768px:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .z-slide-wrap {
   display: none;
   }
}
```

Than use JavaScript to initialize slider only if width is below 768px:

```
if (window.innerWidth <= 768) {
  var slider1 = new Slider('#demo', '.z-slide-item', {
      // OPTIONS HERE
  });
}
```

Comment: thanks for your comment. its really working, but when we resize again more than 768 how to stop the script ?

Comment: Im not sure what you mean. Do you want to hide the slider or stop the script completely?